# Regex to match sentence with abbrevation

Tags: regex, mongodb

I'm using regex with MongoDB query for a search. I want to match the text with its abbreviation,

For example, the collection is something like,

`{title: "Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheeps}`,

My search text could be `DADES`.

Current query is,

```
db.collection.find({title: {$regex: "android", $options: "i"}})
```

I want to match the above entry for `DADES`.

Note: The country name is just an example, and the text will be dynamic.

Comment: People who downvote, could you please comment the reason ?

Comment: What do you mean by *dynamic*? Give us some more examples.

Comment: What is the logic between `united` matching with `USA`? Is it because the first character of `united` is also the first character of a word `USA`? More examples and acceptance criteria would help us help you.

Comment: @pacholik I changed the example to book titles. So there can be a lot of book titles and it keeps on adding. I mean I need a generic solution, cannot keep a dataset for matching.

Comment: @MokkyMiah I guess the example was confusing, so I changed that to book titles.   My current search implementation gives results `United states of America` when I search `United`. But I want a solution, that can give the same result when I search `USA` or `US`

Comment: @RobinCSamuel can you give more sample inputs?

Comment: @TheScientificMethod `TDWP` should give me `The Devil Wears Prada`. `EINTU` should give ` Everything I Never Told You `.

Comment: Try this: (\b[USA]\w*\s*)+

Comment: How are you passing the search text?

Comment: @pacholik I can change the query to something like `db.collection.find({title: {$regex: "(\b[USA]\w*\s*)+ ", $options: "i"}})
`

Comment: Can you change to something like `U.*S.*A.*`?

Answer (score 1):

Edited based on additional acceptance criteria given by OP;

Try the following regex;

`^([USA]\w+\s*)+(?!of)$`

This would match against the following examples;

`United States of America`

`United States America`

This would ignore the following;

`United Kingdom`

You can add additional `words` to ignore by adding them in `(?!of|and|or)`. In this example I am ignoring the words;

`of`

`and`

`or`

Comment: You may want to add case insensitive flag.

Comment: Almost there, this regex works. But not with the MongoDB query. For some reasons `\b` is not working properly in the query.

Comment: Try without the `\b`, should give you same result based on your examples.

Comment: Oh yes, it works. But there is another problem. It matches `United Kingdom` as well, when I search `USA`

Comment: Wouldn't United states of america abbreviate to `USOA`? If you want to match all words then use `^([USA]\w+\s*)+$` instead. In this case it would only match to `united state america` if you want `united states of america`  then use `^([USOA]\w+\s*)+$`

Comment: that didn't work. USA makes more sense, I understand what you meant. But people search USA for united states right? I think we can rely on the capital letters. I can pass only capital letters and make it case sensitive.

Comment: @RobinCSamuel I have edited my answer based on your updated requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by @pacholik,

`db.collection.find({title: {$regex: "U.*S.*.A.*", $options: "i"}})`

Gives me the best result. I'll build the regex based on search text.

Thanks!